# Install PyQt and other python modules for multiple versions in MAC OS X Mavericks

Tags: python, macos, pyqt

I have shed blood sweat and tears to make a python environment working in MAC OS Mavericks.

**THE DATA/FACTS:**

- OS: MAC OS X Mavericks
- What I am trying to do: install some modules in python directories so I can import them later and use them in code, like PyQt4 or 5
- What have I done: Installed installed homebrew, brew installed python 3.3, installed pip, installed easy_install, pip installed numpy, gtk etc.
- OS X has pre-installed python 2.7
- which python: /usr/bin/python
- which python3: /usr/local/bin/python3

**THE PROBLEM:**
I get a message that the library cannot be found when I import it through python prompt.

I have basic unix commands knowledge and I am a beginner in python. Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: What did `pip` say where it installed your modules to? And what does `python -c "import sys; print sys.path"` output?

Comment: it installs them on the python 2.7 default path. The sys.path displays python's 2.7 dirs also.

Comment: it seems that must be a problem with $PYTHONPATH somehow.

Comment: can you look for PyQT in     ls /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/

Comment: or /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ rather?

Comment: yes, it's nothing in both directories. In the second one there is pip and easy_install files only.

Comment: Hasn't anyone worked ever with MAC and Qt in python ?

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same problem few weeks back, while installing kivy and accessing it from terminal in Mac OSX Mavericks.

you can edit the .bash_profile file or create a virtualEnv

I found create a VirtualEnv, where you can create and isolated python dev environment and install packages that you want to use.The following links will guide you to do that and learn to use VirtualEnv

you can learn about VirtualEnv using 
http://iamzed.com/2009/05/07/a-primer-on-virtualenv/

then you can use the tutorial below to build your ....in Mac OSX

http://www.lowindata.com/2013/installing-scientific-python-on-mac-os-x/

go to your home directory ~/ and type ls -al for viewing all hidden files 
locate .bash_profile  and view using nano .bash_profile
you may have multiple files or files like .bash_profile.pysave which you can delete and edit your .bash_profile and set the path as mentioned in the tutorial above.if you don't have one create one.

creating a virtualEnv works best for using python and installing all modules locally..

```
which python
```

output:after creating a virtualEnv.https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i was able to fix it by creating symbolic links from the PyQt4/5 modules at our desired Virtualenv.
So Because we installed Qt and PyQt4/5 with brew it is not located together with our system modules, so when we create a environment, virtualenv does not know how to get it, so we have do do it manually. I did it through a shell script. But there may be better ways of doing it.

So, in order to do that i run this lines of code within my virtualenv root:

```
#!/bin/bash
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/sip/4.15.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sip.so lib/python2.7/site-packages/sip.so
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/sip/4.15.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sipconfig.py lib/python2.7/site-packages/sipconfig.py
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/sip/4.15.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sipdistutils.py lib/python2.7/site-packages/sipdistutils.py
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4 lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4
```

It may not be needed to create all of the symlinks above, as i understand just the PtQt4/5 folder and the sip.so will do the trick.

After doing that you should be able to import the PyQt4/5 modules from your python environment.

Editing to link a video tutorial on how to fix the issue:
[video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFF9IQImOOo)